# setInterval starts my page to lag when it generates 30 plus data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, json

can anyone help me with my problem with setInterval because it starts to lagg like `pause and resume` thing happens in my page if it generate `30 plus more data` in my static `textboxes` in my page. Does anyone know how to solve the lagg issue in my problem?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

var $funiq_id         = $('#funiq_id'),
    $t_region         = $('#t_region'),
    $t_town           = $('#t_town'),
    $t_uniq_id        = $('#t_uniq_id'),
    $t_position       = $('#t_position'),
    $t_salary_grade   = $('#t_salary_grade'),
    $t_salary         = $('#t_salary');
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function updateTextboxes(){
        $.ajax({
        url:"search.php",
        type:"GET",
        data: { term : $('#query').val() },
        dataType:"JSON",
        success: function(result) {

        var ii = 1;

        for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) { 
                    $funiq_id.html(result[i].value).show(); 
                    $t_region.val(result[i].region).show().trigger('input');
                    $t_town.val(result[i].town).show().trigger('input'); 
                    $t_uniq_id.val(result[i].uniq_id).show().trigger('input'); 
                    $t_position.val(result[i].position).show().trigger('input');
                    $t_salary_grade.val(result[i].salary_grade).show().trigger('input'); 
                    $t_salary.val(result[i].salary).show().trigger('input');
                    $('#id'+ii+'').val(result[i].atid).show().trigger('input');
                    $('#aic'+ii+'').val(result[i].atic).show().trigger('input');
                    $('#name'+ii+'').val(result[i].atname).show().trigger('input');
                    $('#other_qual'+ii+'').val(result[i].other_sum).show().trigger('input');
                    $('#interview'+ii+'').val(result[i].interview_sum).show().trigger('input');
                    $('#optA'+ii+'').val(result[i].edu_attain2_sum).show().trigger('input');
                    $('#optB'+ii+'').val(result[i].experience2_sum).show().trigger('input');
                    $('#optC'+ii+'').val(result[i].trainings2_sum).show().trigger('input');
                    $('#optD'+ii+'').val(result[i].eligibility2_sum).show().trigger('input');
                    $('#total'+ii+'').val(result[i].final_total_sum).show().trigger('input');
                    $(':input').removeAttr('placeholder');
            ii++;
            }

        }


    });


},500);
         $('.search_form_input').val('');
         $('.search_textbox').val('');
         $(".empty_batchcode").html("");
         $('#execute').prop('disabled', true);


});      
</script>
```

Comment: You should rethink your logic firstly using a timeout, not interval and recall timeout in ajax complete callback. Anyway, you seem to do too much for so little space time. And i don't really understand why you'd need to call it in an interval/timeout and not using instead relevant handler as onchange event of textbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are performing an asynchronous request every 500 milliseconds, so it is likely that they will start queueing up and your browser will not be able to complete them in time.

You could increase the interval, but you would be better off to remove `setInterval` and only do another request when it finishes i.e. inside your `success` function:

E.g.

```
success: function(result) {
...
//at the end of the function
updateTextboxes(); //or setTimeout(updateTextboxes, 500);
}
```

If you want to only call it after your input changes, then you can remove the `setInterval/setTimeout` altogether and just attach to the [onblur](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onblur.asp) or [onkeydown](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeydown.asp) events e.g.

```
<input id='search' type="text" onkeydown="updateTextboxes()">
```

or using jQuery

```
$('#search').change(updateTextboxes);
```

Comment: if i remove the setInterval and only do another request when it finishes my whole script wont work.

Comment: the setinterval from my script is the one making my script work all the time if i type in my searchbox input.

Comment: In that case you only need to call `updateTextboxes` when the value of your search input changes. So you could attach it to the `onkeydown` or `onblur` event e.g. `<input onblur='updateTextBoxes()'/>`

Comment: i tried the keydown and blur event but my data wont shows up so the last resort of mine is the setInterval

Comment: Try using jQuery change (as above). If jQuery or blur/keydown is not working, then you need to put an alert or something inside `updateTextboxes` to make sure that it is getting called. Also see if there are any JavaScript errors on your page.